# tensorflow - convolution + lstm

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement the architecture of figure 1 from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4389.pdf

I have followed the lstm tutorials on tensorflow but that has not helped me because the input data is not convolved in time. I need to run CNN on **each** frame in a sequence then feed it to the lstm. Is anyone aware of any sample code for this ?

Comment: Did you get any further by now?

Comment: yes i found out how to use it

Comment: would you mind sharing your knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an architecture like this for multi-channel time series data, by *unrolling* the convolutional network in time and feeding the concatenated output tensors into the LSTM network. The LSTM network is created by standard `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell`, `tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

A better approach to unrolling in time would be to use `tf.while_loop` to create the convolutional part of the network.

The following code illustrates the idea, but is untested.

```py
conv_outputs = [None]*len(iterator)
with tf.variable_scope("ConvNet"):
    for idx, frame in enumerate(frames):
        # assuming the shared weight and bias variables were created beforehand
        for i, (weights, bias) in enumerate(conv_maps):
            with tf.name_scope("Conv{}".format(i)):
                conv_out = tf.add(
                    tf.nn.conv2d(
                        conv_in,  # [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
                        weights,  # [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                        padding="VALID", name="Conv{}".format(i)),
                    bias, name="Add{}".format(i))
                conv_out = tf.nn.relu(conv_out, name="Relu{}".format(i))
            with tf.name_scope("Pool{}".format(i)):
                pool_out = tf.nn.max_pool(
                    conv_out,  # [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
                    ksize=[1, pool_size, 1, 1],
                    strides=[1, pool_size, 1, 1],
                    padding='VALID', name="Pool{}".format(i))
           conv_outputs[idx] = pool_out
           conv_in = pool_out
    stacked = tf.stack(conv_outputs, 1)
    reshaped = tf.reshape(stacked, [-1, len(conv_outputs), conv_outputs[-1].shape[-1])  # [batch_size, num_frames, last_layer_feature_maps

num_lstm_cells = [8, 8]

cell_series = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell(n) for n in num_lstm_cells]
layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell_series, state_is_tuple=True)

# prediction of the LSTM network for input batch_x
net_out, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(layers, reshaped, dtype=tf.float32)
```